# Error code 100 (Can only call this method on valid test users for your app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

getting the error {"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app","type":"OAuthException"}} whenever trying to write to any facebook end point. Reading (GET) works fine, writing (POST) fails. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

I have also opened a ticket on FB dev site:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/184198634991192?browse=search_4e93328871c8a3231774584

The problem does not occur is I would shoot the POST request from my browser as if I am the user.
The problem does occurs only when sending from our servers on behalf of the user from one of our dev machines which have other subdomain names instead of www (such as dev1.blablabla.com & dev2.blablabla.com, while the app is registered to www.blablabla.com).

So the question is, does facebook attempt to do a reverse DNS lookup on all write requests to verify the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your requirement is to get the user details of the owner of Facebook access token (normally the currently logged in user)

For that you have to issue a **GET** request and **not** a **POST** request. 
The reason why it works when fired from the browser is that when you submit a query through the address bar it is send as a **GET** request, and when sent from your server it is send as **POST** and fails producing the error message mentioned in your post.

Facebook doesn't do a reverse DNS lookup on your write request and not need to configure anything in your server related to it.

Hope the answer is clear enough for you.